# Serverless Framework - reuse environment variables in github workflow

Tags: aws-lambda, continuous-integration, serverless-framework, continuous-deployment

I'm configuring the github workflow to deploy a **lambda** application that uses the **serverless** framework, but my nodejs project has many environment variables, however in the serverless dashboard i already defined all of them, but to build the project within the workflow **Github**, i need the environment variables, but i would not like to set them again within github secrets, as I have already defined them once inside the **serverless** dashboard.

I would like to know if there is any way to reuse the variables that are inside serveless, instead of setting it all over again within the **Github** environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible to retrieve them using `sls param list` or `sls param get --name <name-of-param>` commands. You will have to parse the output of these commands to set the environment variables as that is not done automatically.

Comment: this is perfect, i created a sh script to get parameters and set in .env file:

`echo MYSQL_PASSWORD=$(echo $(serverless param get --name MYSQL_PASSWORD --stage $ENV) | grep -o '[^/ ]\+$') >> .env`

Now I have the .env file with the variables exactly as I defined it in the serveless dashboard.